# Count sequences of data rows given condition

Tags: java

I have a file were rows are of the form `IPAddress:Timestamp` (IP Address is in the usuak IPv4 notation, timestamp in seconds from the epoch).

I'd like to count how many times the following event happens: it begins a sequence of rows such that for every two rows that have the same IP address, the difference between their timestamp is `< 240`.

Let me explain further:

Given

```
1.2.3.4:0
1.2.3.4:50
1.2.3.4:60
1.2.3.4:70
5.6.7.8:80
1.2.3.4:1500
1.2.3.4:1600
```

I should get the result `2`, because rows 1,2,3,4 form such a sequence, and rows 6,7 form another one.

This is what I tried (using Java, let Row be a class that summarizes the data of a row in the file):

```java
int count = 0;
        HashMap<String, Long> t = new HashMap<>();

        for (Map.Entry<String, List<Row>> entry : IP_MAP.entrySet()) {
            List<Row> list = entry.getValue();
            t.put(entry.getKey(), 0L);

            for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
                long d = list.get(i + 1).getTimestamp() - list.get(i).getTimestamp();
                if (d > 0 && d < FOUR_MINUTES && list.get(i).getTimestamp() - t.get(entry.getKey()) > FOUR_MINUTES) {

                    count++;
                }
                t.put(entry.getKey(), list.get(i).getTimestamp());
            }
        }

        return count;
}
```

Where the timestamp is stored as a `long`, IP address as a `String` and `FOUR_MINUTES` is a long that is equal to `240`. (240 seconds = 4 mins).

The problem is that my result is always too low.

What could be the problem in my code?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What does entry.getKey() return? You seem to be ignoring the fact that you can have different sequences for the same IP. Take your example, you have two sequences for the IP 1.2.3.4, but in your code if getKey returns the same then you will be only counting it as one sequence.

Comment: entry.getKey() gives a String back (the IP address). The IP_MAP is a Map<String, List<Row>> where each IP address is mapped to a list of all Rows associated with that ip

Comment: Right, so if the interval between two sequences is less than 240, how can you differentiate them? In your example, what if 1500 was instead 90?

Comment: It's considered one sequence and not 2

Comment: And your list is already sorted by timestamp?

Comment: Yes, it is, sorry for not having written that

Comment: Get examples and try debugging line by line until you find the bug. I honestly didn't look at your code deep enough. If you provide some test cases I could try.